# Ember.js Assertion Failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading my application from ember 1.13 to 2.5. Now I am getting an error "Assertion Failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]" with no stacktrace.

I am using ember-cli 2.5.0.

I have looked through every file I have that brings in a mixin (over 100) and none of them seem wrong. What is the best way to try to track down where this error is coming from?

Comment: throw a breakpoint at the error and track it back to find out what object is being requested to be created, walk up the stack trace.

Comment: I had tried that. The stack trace I get when I do that has no calls in any of my code. It is coming from backburner, of which I know nothing.

Comment: That is the best way to track it down, you can go up the call stack, check out the code, find out which type of object it is trying to create, and which mixin it's trying to use when it creates that object.  If you don't want to do it that way, you can brute force it and throw some debuggers before the class definitions and make sure none of the mixed in mixins are null.

Comment: That worked and wasn't as painful as I expected it to be. Thanks.